# Error in calling hooks somwhere in the code

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and facing this error "Invalid hook call for any of these reasons"

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I have checked all the conditions on the official website there are no issue

Here is error which is being shown in the first line "this.setState()"

```
 this.setState({
      lat: lat,
      lon: lon,
      city: data.name,
      temperatureC: Math.round(data.main.temp),
      temperatureF: Math.round(data.main.temp * 1.8 + 32),
      humidity: data.main.humidity,
      main: data.weather[0].main,
      country: data.sys.country,
      // sunrise: this.getTimeFromUnixTimeStamp(data.sys.sunrise),

      // sunset: this.getTimeFromUnixTimeStamp(data.sys.sunset),
    });
```

The main program is this

```
import React from "react";
import apiKeys from "./apiKeys";
import Clock from "react-live-clock";
import Forcast from "./forcast";
import loader from "./images/WeatherIcons.gif";
import ReactAnimatedWeather from "react-animated-weather";
const dateBuilder = (d) => {
  let months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];
  let days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];

  let day = days[d.getDay()];
  let date = d.getDate();
  let month = months[d.getMonth()];
  let year = d.getFullYear();

  return `${day}, ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
};
const defaults = {
  color: "white",
  size: 112,
  animate: true,
};
class Weather extends React.Component {
  state = {
    lat: undefined,
    lon: undefined,
    errorMessage: undefined,
    temperatureC: undefined,
    temperatureF: undefined,
    city: undefined,
    country: undefined,
    humidity: undefined,
    description: undefined,
    icon: "CLEAR_DAY",
    sunrise: undefined,
    sunset: undefined,
    errorMsg: undefined,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      this.getPosition()
        //If user allow location service then will fetch data & send it to get-weather function.
        .then((position) => {
          this.getWeather(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          //If user denied location service then standard location weather will le shown on basis of latitude & latitude.
          this.getWeather(28.67, 77.22);
          alert(
            "You have disabled location service. Allow 'This APP' to access your location. Your current location will be used for calculating Real time weather."
          );
        });
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation not available");
    }

    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.getWeather(this.state.lat, this.state.lon),
      600000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  // tick = () => {
  //   this.getPosition()
  //   .then((position) => {
  //     this.getWeather(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
  //   })
  //   .catch((err) => {
  //     this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message });
  //   });
  // }

  getPosition = (options) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
    });
  };
  getWeather = async (lat, lon) => {
    const api_call = await fetch(
      `${apiKeys.base}weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&APPID=${apiKeys.key}`
    );
    const data = await api_call.json();
    this.setState({
      lat: lat,
      lon: lon,
      city: data.name,
      temperatureC: Math.round(data.main.temp),
      temperatureF: Math.round(data.main.temp * 1.8 + 32),
      humidity: data.main.humidity,
      main: data.weather[0].main,
      country: data.sys.country,
      // sunrise: this.getTimeFromUnixTimeStamp(data.sys.sunrise),

      // sunset: this.getTimeFromUnixTimeStamp(data.sys.sunset),
    });
    switch (this.state.main) {
      case "Haze":
        this.setState({ icon: "CLEAR_DAY" });
        break;
      case "Clouds":
        this.setState({ icon: "CLOUDY" });
        break;
      case "Rain":
        this.setState({ icon: "RAIN" });
        break;
      case "Snow":
        this.setState({ icon: "SNOW" });
        break;
      case "Dust":
        this.setState({ icon: "WIND" });
        break;
      case "Drizzle":
        this.setState({ icon: "SLEET" });
        break;
      case "Fog":
        this.setState({ icon: "FOG" });
        break;
      case "Smoke":
        this.setState({ icon: "FOG" });
        break;
      case "Tornado":
        this.setState({ icon: "WIND" });
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({ icon: "CLEAR_DAY" });
    }
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.temperatureC) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="city">
            <div className="title">
              <h2>{this.state.city}</h2>
              <h3>{this.state.country}</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-icon">
              {" "}
              <ReactAnimatedWeather
                icon={this.state.icon}
                color={defaults.color}
                size={defaults.size}
                animate={defaults.animate}
              />
              <p>{this.state.main}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="date-time">
              <div className="dmy">
                <div id="txt"></div>
                <div className="current-time">
                  <Clock format="HH:mm:ss" interval={1000} ticking={true} />
                </div>
                <div className="current-date">{dateBuilder(new Date())}</div>
              </div>
              <div className="temperature">
                <p>
                  {this.state.temperatureC}°<span>C</span>
                </p>
                {/* <span className="slash">/</span>
                {this.state.temperatureF} &deg;F */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Forcast icon={this.state.icon} weather={this.state.main} />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <img src={loader} style={{ width: "50%", WebkitUserDrag: "none" }} />
          <h3 style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "22px", fontWeight: "600" }}>
            Detecting your location
          </h3>
          <h3 style={{ color: "white", marginTop: "10px" }}>
            Your current location wil be displayed on the App <br></br> & used
            for calculating Real time weather.
          </h3>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Weather;
```

Comment: Im not seeing any hook calls. If there were any, the error would obviously be from calling a hook in a class component.
Maybe I am missing something, are you using any react hooks?